# What does "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: src == this" mean?

Tags: java, android, bytebuffer

I got the following exception when call `java.nio.ByteBuffer.put(ByteBuffer.java)`

```
11-09 22:11:55.631 E/AndroidRuntime( 1616): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-701
11-09 22:11:55.631 E/AndroidRuntime( 1616): Process: com.jerikc.demo, PID: 1616 
11-09 22:11:55.631 E/AndroidRuntime( 1616): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: src == this 
11-09 22:11:55.631 E/AndroidRuntime( 1616):     at java.nio.ByteBuffer.put(ByteBuffer.java:749)
```

What does that mean? How to fix it?

Comment: can you show your code please!

Comment: obviously you have somthing like `ByteBuffer buff = ByteBuffer.allocate(10); buff.put(buff);` (or more hidden: `ByteBuffer other = buff; buff.put(other);`)

Comment: more info would be very good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the source buffer is this buffer you see this message

you are putting an object to itself

see line 734  http://www.jsourcecode.com/class.php?proj=jdk%5Copenjdk&jar=openjdk-6-b14&class=java.nio.ByteBuffer